# How to query a variable number of rows from a values list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

My situation is that I need to produce a number of rows from a fixed list
The fixed list has 11 rows, and I need to select a variable number of rows from it

I can do it like this

```
select r.ritid, r.loadfactor, cvirtual.ProductSequence
from   rit r
outer apply ( select top 5 --r.loadfactor
                     RitID,
                     CarID,
                     row_number() over (partition by RitID order by RitID) as ProductSequence
              from ( values(r.RitID, 1),
                           (r.RitID, 2),
                           (r.RitID, 3),
                           (r.RitID, 4),
                           (r.RitID, 5),
                           (r.RitID, 6),
                           (r.RitID, 7),
                           (r.RitID, 8),
                           (r.RitID, 9),
                           (r.RitID, 10),
                           (r.RitID, 11)
                   ) as X(RitID, CarId)
              --where  c.CarID is null
            ) cvirtual
```

This will get me 5 rows from the list,
but I don't want to write `top 5` but something like `top r.LoadFactor` which is not possible off course.

So, how could I do this ?
Without using dynamic sql please

**[You can find a DBFiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=944feee8130647adbff79d019a432b0d)** with my data and my attempt

If in table `rit` the column `LoadFactor` is 3 then I want this result

```
ritid   loadfactor  ProductSequence
1       5           1
1       5           2
1       5           3
```

If in table `rit` the column `LoadFactor` is 5 then I want this result

```
ritid   loadfactor  ProductSequence
1       5           1
1       5           2
1       5           3
1       5           4
1       5           5
```

Comment: It *is* possible, though. The syntax just needs parentheses -- `TOP(r.LoadFactor)`. Parameterized `TOP` has been a thing since SQL Server 2005. Do take care to include an `ORDER BY` as well, otherwise your `TOP` is violently nondeterministic, which *will* bite you at an inopportune moment.

Comment: @JeroenMostert There are opportune moments to get bitten ? :)

Comment: Let's say that I've read some vampire fiction that suggests there are and leave it at that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73039419/how-to-query-a-variable-number-of-rows-from-a-values-list#comment129000777_73039419) it is possible to use `top` with a column as you can see in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c5eeac2b9daf22228c8e3209ef4ee9e) but you need to add parenthesis around column name, example `top(r.loadfactor)`.

So if `r.loadfactor` is 3 it will return only 3 rows, and if it's 5 it will return 5 rows. Just add `order by` to the `top` results.

Running your query with a `update` on loadfactor as shown here:

```sql
update rit
set loadfactor = 3

select r.ritid, r.loadfactor, cvirtual.ProductSequence
from   rit r
outer apply ( select top(r.loadfactor)
                     RitID,
                     CarID,
                     row_number() over (partition by RitID order by RitID) as ProductSequence
              from ( values(r.RitID, 1),
                           (r.RitID, 2),
                           (r.RitID, 3),
                           (r.RitID, 4),
                           (r.RitID, 5),
                           (r.RitID, 6),
                           (r.RitID, 7),
                           (r.RitID, 8),
                           (r.RitID, 9),
                           (r.RitID, 10),
                           (r.RitID, 11)
                   ) as X(RitID, CarId)
              --where  c.CarID is null
            ) cvirtual --on r.RitID = cvirtual.RitID
```

Returns:

```
+------+------------+-----------------+
| ritid| loadfactor | ProductSequence |
+------+------------+-----------------+
|1     | 3          | 1               |
|1     | 3          | 2               |
|1     | 3          | 3               |
+------+------------+-----------------+
```

And really I should add more, that when you have a value in your table it really is like a variable saved in your table, so the same as you can have `select top 3` you can also have `select top(@value)` of 3, but the reason you need to enclose it in parenthesis is because SQL doesn't know if you want to display the value of @value or the column name, or you want to use it as a value for top. At least when using a int SQL would understand it as a value for top when using `select`.

So in summery the same as you can use the literal value if 3, you can also use the variable that has a value of 3, and you can also use a column (with one row) that is nothing more than a variable saved in a table structure, that has a value of 3.

Comment: omg it  had no idea it was that easy,thanks